# CSS3 allowed in email?

Tags: email, html5, css3

I cannot find any answers or discussions if CSS3 is allowed in HTML emails from the search box.  I am wanting to update my company newsletters and campaigns but I don't know what properties are allowed.  A list similar to a browser list would be awesome.  Does anyone have a list that identifies the CSS properties that can be used for emails?

Comment: On my campaigns I try to avoid because the problem isn't that its not allowed its the fact that mail companies filter emails and believe its spam... like even today its best to use inline styling.

Comment: I will use inline styling but my issue is what can go in and what cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Campaign Monitor people maintain a big [table of CSS support in various mail clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). There's a changelog at bottom with running notes, and a bunch of CSS3 properties(mostly decorative) were initially added [April 2010](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3107/css3-support-in-email-clients/).